# Validates Data in Rails 3.1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

My application use two  varariables to take notes about product warranty start time and warranty end time;so in my view I use two dropdown menu to select start and end times. 
Now, I must sure that start time shouldn't greater than end time. In witch way can I model this restriction? I've tried with the following code in my model file:

```
  validates_numericality_of :warranty_end, :greater_than => :warranty_start
```

but I've seen that it doesn't work!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Off course 'warranty_end' and 'warranty_start' are two date type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use variables in `validates` like that, but you can create a custom validator like this

```
validates_numericality_of :warranty_end
validate :warranty_end_less_than_warranty_start

...

def warranty_end_less_than_warranty_start
  unless warranty_end > warranty_start
    errors.add :warranty_end, "must be before the warranty starting date"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work (in 3.2 at least).  From the docs at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html:

```
validates_numericality_of :width, :less_than => Proc.new { |person| person.height } 
validates_numericality_of :width, :greater_than => :minimum_weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Azolo now it's works! The only thing is that you delete "validates_numericality_of :warranty_end" statement, so working code for me is:

```
validate :warranty_end_less_than_warranty_start

...

def warranty_end_less_than_warranty_start
  unless warranty_end > warranty_start
    errors.add :warranty_end, "must be before the warranty starting date"
  end
end
```

Thank you all again